# How to manage session in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring. There is a Controlle called `userController`. In this controller there is method called `signIn`. In this method is user entered correct userid and password then page redirect to the same view with session values. Then user can check his profile details. For that i have created a method call `account` in the userController. In this method i can not get the previously set session values.How can i get it? This is my implementation of two method.
this is`signIn` method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sign_in", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signIn(@RequestHeader(value = "Accept") String headerAccept,@ModelAttribute User requestParamUser,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs,HttpSession session) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        // Check request parameters are null
        if ((requestParamUser.getUserId() == null)|| (requestParamUser.getPassword() == null)) {
            obj.put("loginError", CommonConfig.REQUEST_PARAMETERS_ARE_NULL);
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("state", obj);
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("user",requestParamUser);
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        User user = userDAO.findByUserIdAndPassword(requestParamUser.getUserId(),requestParamUser.getPassword());

        // Check provide userId and password is correct
        if (user == null) {
            obj.put("loginError", CommonConfig.USER_NOT_FOUND);
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("state", obj);
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("user",requestParamUser);
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        obj.put("loginSuccess", CommonConfig.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("state", obj);
        session.setAttribute("userId",user.getUserId());
        session.setAttribute("userName",user.getFirstName());
        return "redirect:/";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(CommonConfig.DB_ERROR + " : "+ e.getMessage().toString());
        obj.put("loginError", CommonConfig.DB_ERROR);
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("state", obj);
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("user",requestParamUser);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

This is the `account` method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ac")
    public String account(@RequestHeader(value = "Accept") String headerAccept,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, HttpServletRequest request){

        String userId = (String) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userId");
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("abc",userId);
        return "account";   
    }
```

in this method i'm trying to test the `session` veriable to `redirectAttrs`. That value will show in `account` view. Problem is in this method. I can not get the `userId` session veriable.

Comment: You can use spring security to do login and store userInfo, It's better and more safe, If it's acceptable for you i can show you example.

Comment: @SafwanHijazi plz show me a example. tx

Comment: please see the example below, and please ask me if you have any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should add spring security libs, then do the following:

create new class that implements this UserDetailsService like this:

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService and implement loadUserByUsername

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userInfo)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // use userInfo to check user Info then return object from UserDetails class
    String[] tokens=userInfo.split("@0@");
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities= new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    // here you pass the Role so you can use later in your application
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("ROLE_"+tokens[2]));
    UserDetails userDetails = new User(tokens[0],tokens[1], authorities);
    return userDetails;
}
```

Now Add these lines in spring configuration file to define authentication manager:

```
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
   class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
 </bean>
   <bean id="userDetailsService" class="yourPackage.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>

   <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">

        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager >
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">

        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
```

Here you define authentication manager, then you can use in login controller like this:

```
Authentication authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username+"@0@"+password+"@0@"+response.getOperatorInfo().getRole_name(), password);

                    Authentication result=null;
                    try {
                        result = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
```

Finally in other Controller you can take the userInfo like this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()
```

Comment: Thanks. The constructor GrantedAuthorityImpl(String) is deprecated. What is alternate ?

Comment: use this authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("ROLE_"+tokens[2]));

Comment: <sec:> namespace and location ? i put it but not working

Comment: define it as namespace in xml configuration file like this:
    xmlns:sec="shttp://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

Comment: what is response.getOperatorInfo().getRole_name() ? Is that response is HttpServletResponse ?

Comment: `authenticationManager` ?